# New version of Thunderbird mail client for Raspbian/Debian

Tags: raspbian, debian

How I can get newer Thunderbird for Raspberry Pi?

I know its name is Icedove on [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Corporation_software_rebranded_by_the_Debian_project) and I can install it with `apt-get install icedove` but its available version of it on Raspbian repositories currently (1/14/2013) is 10.0.11 while Thunderbird official version is 17.0.2 now.

How I can have a newer (> 15) version? (without compiling Thunderbird on Raspberry Pi!)

Comment: I installed it from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=150438&p=989236#p989236) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Thunderbird seem to be quite heavy-wight for the Pi, maybe that's the reason there are no up-to-date builds. [Claws](http://www.claws-mail.org/) might be a good alternative for you: `apt-get update && apt-get install claws-mail`